# I'm reading up on building an SSR using MOSFETs, and there is something I don't understand

Tags: mosfet, solid-state-relay

[image]

This [webpage](https://www.homemade-circuits.com/solid-state-relay-ssr-circuit-using-mosfets/) goes over building an SSR using MOSFETs.

The author says that in this SSR design there may be problems in its implementation because:

> A closer look at the above design suggests that, this SSR design might have problems implementing the intended function efficiently. This is because, the moment the switching DC arrives at the gate of the MOSFET, it will begin turning ON, causing a bypassing of the current through the drain/source, depleting the gate/source voltage.

> Let's consider the MOSFET T1. As soon as the rectified DC begins reaching the gate of T1, it will begin turning ON right from around 4 V onward, causing a bypassing effect of the the supply via its drain/source terminals. During this moment, the DC will struggle to rise across the zener diode and begin dropping toward zero.

> This will in turn cause the MOSFET to turn OFF, and the continuous stale-mate kind of struggle or a tug of war will occur between the MOSFET drain/source and the MOSFET gate/source, preventing the SSR from functioning correctly.

What does the author mean by this?

Comment: It's a poor design but, what the author is talking about appears to miss the point. However, don't use that as a SSR.

Comment: @Andyaka I don't plan to. My basis in electronics is very weak so I try to learn and understand anything electronics related I come across.

Comment: @xrosaber Be aware that there's a lot of complete nonsense and bad practice out there on the internet, so don't expect everything you come across to be something sensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the author of the extract in your post is saying that "the supply to the capacitor" will no longer exist once T1 or T2 turns on because they will short the "supply" voltage. C1 may keep the circuit operational for a while but it will discharge through the 100k and 1k resistors and have no way to charge up again until the circuit fails to turn on. The result will be intermittent operation.

Answer (score 0):

Capacitor is charged through D1 and T2. From begining both transistors are "OFF", current is going through "parasitic" diode only half base. At moment T1 is "ON", it shorting capacitor and and it will be discharged over the time. No DC, no control voltage, transistors are "OFF", process of charging capacitor starts. DC power supply should be fed from main voltage and some resistor in charging circuit required to limit charge current.

Comment: How is the capacitor shorted when T1 closes? The only "discharge path" is through D1, D2, and the 100k resistor; if you look at the connections at the capacitor's positive terminal. Ignoring the 100k resistor, the capacitor can't discharge through D1 and D2. Therefore, there is no way for the capacitor to get shorted when T1 closes.

Comment: Capacitor with D1 is connected in parallel with T1. Then T1 is on, drop voltage low, capasitor discharge trough 100k resistor and zenner and 100k resistor, optotransistor and 1k resistor.